# SignalR - Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

How to properly manage the error of **SignalR**

> Unable to connect to the remote server

Have I just put the same method to `catch (Exception ex) {}` block?
Or perhaps there is another way to do it.

Thank you!

```
 public void StartEventSniffer()
        {
            try
            {
                #region Create HubConnection
                var connection = new HubConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.HostNotificationURL);
                _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationManager");
                connection.Start().Wait();
                #endregion

                #region ATM/Host Connection Events
                _hub.On(HostNotificationManagerMethods.ValidATMConnected.ToString(), x =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                       //Some code
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.Error(ex);
                    }
                });

                _hub.Invoke(HostNotificationManagerMethods.ValidATMConnected.ToString(), null).Wait();

                #endregion               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex);

                StartEventSniffer(); // Reconnect
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you have a high number of exceptions you'll overflow the stack. Maybe run it in a loop with 10 retries or so and then stop trying? You'll `break;` from the loop direct after the Invoke call.

Comment: @rene Do you think to use some Timer to establish connection is a good idea? And in case of the error just start this Timer again?

Comment: But that introduces another thread with it's complexities. If your only concern is handling an occasional connect failure, using a loop with a limit number of retries is the easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used combination of the `Timer` and **SignalR connection events**.

```
namespace MyAppManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        #region Properties
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private bool _shutdown;
        private readonly MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;
        internal static MainWindow Main;
        IHubProxy _hub;
        HubConnection connection;

        Timer hubTimer;
        #endregion

        #region Delegates
        public class ValidATMConnectedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public ATMItem ATM { set; get; }

            public ValidATMConnectedEventArgs(ATMItem atm)
            {
                ATM = atm;
            }
        }
        public delegate void ValidATMConnectedEventHandler(object sender, ValidATMConnectedEventArgs e); 

        #endregion

        #region Events

        public event ValidATMConnectedEventHandler ValidATMConnectedEvent;
        public void OnValidATMConnected(ValidATMConnectedEventArgs e)
        {
            ValidATMConnectedEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Ctor
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            hubTimer = new Timer();
            hubTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000).TotalMilliseconds;
            hubTimer.Elapsed += HubTimer_Elapsed;

            _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(DialogCoordinator.Instance);
            DataContext = _viewModel;

            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void HubTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                hubTimer.Enabled = false;
                StartEventSniffer();
                hubTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Internal events
        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Main = this;

            #region Create HubConnection
            connection = new HubConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.HostNotificationURL);

            connection.StateChanged += Connection_StateChanged;
            connection.Error += Connection_Error;
            _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationManager");

            #endregion

            StartEventSniffer();

            hubTimer.Start();
        }

        private void Connection_Error(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                StartEventSniffer();
            }
        }

        public void StartEventSniffer()
        {
            try
            { 
                connection.Start().Wait();

                #region ATM/Host Connection Events
                _hub.On(HostNotificationManagerMethods.ValidATMConnected.ToString(), x =>
                {
                    try
                    {

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.Error(ex);
                    }
                });

                _hub.Invoke(HostNotificationManagerMethods.ValidATMConnected.ToString(), null).Wait();




                #endregion               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }

        private void Connection_StateChanged(StateChange obj)
        {
            if (obj.NewState == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                StartEventSniffer();
            }
        }
        #endregion    

    }
}
```

Comment: some explanation would be useful